# Comparing a String to an Object's toString() method dynamically

Tags: java, object, command

I'm reading from a text file, like so:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] a = line.split("\\: ");
        key = a[0];
        action = a[1];
        gameKeys.add(key, action);
}
```

where the file would be something like

```
SPACE: FIRE_ACTION
E: USE_ACTION
```

This part works, `key` and `action` are both what I want.

`gameKeys` is a `Map` declared like so:

```
private static Map<Keyboard.Key, Action> gameKeys = new HashMap<>();
```

`Keyboard.Key` has fields such as `SPACE`, `A`, `RETURN`, etc.
Action is an interface, that holds other actions; those actions have a `toString()` method that returns the action, e.g. `new FireAction.toString()` returns `FIRE_ACTION`.

Example of an Action:

```
public class FireAction implements Action {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Fire key pressed!");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FIRE_ACTION";
    }
}
```

So, I'm trying to turn the file's components into objects, like if `key` was `"SPACE"` and `action` was `"FIRE_ACTION"`, then, after the `add` method is performed, `gameKeys` would have `<Keyboard.Key.SPACE, new FireAction()>`

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

- Save your `Action` classes in a `Map<String, Class<? extends Action>>`
- Read the Key -> Action bindings from the file
- Resolve the string action to an actual `Action` object via the map

Example:

```
public class Main {
    private static final Map<Keyboard.Key, Action> gameKeys = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<String, Class<? extends Action>> actions = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        actions.put(FireAction.NAME, FireAction.class);
        actions.put(WalkAction.NAME, WalkAction.class);    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // read from file etc.

        try {
            // e.g. found  SPACE : FIRE_ACTION
            gameKeys.put(Keyboard.Key.SPACE, actions.get("FIRE_ACTION").newInstance());

            // e.g. found A : WALK_ACTION
            gameKeys.put(Keyboard.Key.A, actions.get("WALK_ACTION").newInstance());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FireAction implements Action {
    public static final String NAME = "FIRE_ACTION";

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Fire key pressed!");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return NAME;
    }

}
```

Comment: This sounds wonderful, however (this is sort of a dumb question), would I declare the map within the `Action` interface, and then set the map's values in the classes implementing Action?

Comment: @Tetramputechture I would suggest creating the map where you manage your user input (e.g. a class `ActionHandler`). Then only this class knows about the `Action` objects / Key -> Action bindings.

Comment: @Tetramputechture I edited my answer, hope that clears it up :)

Comment: Thank you! I figured out most of my problems, but you helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
Object keyObj = key, actionObj;
if (key.equals("SPACE")) keyObj = Keyboard.Key.SPACE;
if (action.equals("FIRE_ACTION")) actionObj = new FireAction());
```

You can use a Map<String, ...> as an alternative to using 'if's if you have a lot of cases

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve what you have asked directly - because then Java would have to create ALL the classes it can create(some have non-default constructors or even private), and call their toString() method (which may have side-effects in general case).

So anyway you'll have to create registry with all actions(preferrable way), or you can try to use reflection to create Actions in runtime.